# SAS by command lead to missing observation

Tags: sas

I was learning SAS by myself but had a problem about by command.

The sample data:

[image]

The original code is fine:

```
proc print data = sashelp.class;
    var name sex age height weight;
    where age > 14;
    sum weight;
run;
```

But when I added an by command:

```
proc print data = sashelp.class;
    var name sex age height weight;
    where age > 14;
    sum weight;
    by age;
run;
```

The outputs are presented as below:

[image]

Which is strange that observation 17 and 19 are missing. Could you tell me why and how to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your log, you will find the error:

```
ERROR: Data set SASHELP.CLASS is not sorted in ascending sequence. The current BY group has Age = 16 and the next BY group has Age = 15.
```

When using [by-group processing](http://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=p0yeyftk8ftuckn1o5qzy53284gz.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en), you must have the data either sorted or indexed by your `by` variable.

As the data is being processed, SAS is expecting it to already in order, or to have an index that holds the order.

The first three observations happen to already be in the right order, ascending from 15 to 16. Once it gets to the 4th observation, it sees that the by-group value is 15.  It will then error out, stop processing, and in the case of `PROC PRINT`, print the results it obtained before the error. You can solve this by sorting `sashelp.class`:

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class
          out=class;
    by age;
run;

proc print data = class;
    var name sex age height weight;
    where age > 14;
    sum weight;
    by age;
run;
```

SAS procedures generally do not automatically sort by-groups. They must either be sorted or indexed prior to being used.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much for the help and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `notsorted` keyword in the `by` statement; This will handle unsorted data without having to preceded with a `proc sort` statement.

```
proc print data = sashelp.class ;
    var name sex age height weight;
    where age > 14;
    sum weight;
    by age notsorted;
run;
```

Comment: The `notsorted` BY option does **not** sort the data.  NOTSORTED creates groups based on incoming contiguous rows having the same combinations of by values.  The where clause removes rows < 15, so the notsorted groups are Age=15 (two rows), Age=16 (one row) and Age=15 (two rows)

Comment: Thanks for the help, got it.